# Freeze tensor_forest graph for Android

Tags: android, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensor

I built a aimple Random Forest model in tensorflow, and want to freeze & optimize it for android.
I used the following function for building the tesnor_forest estimator:

```
def build_estimator(_model_dir, _num_classes, _num_features, _num_trees, _max_nodes):
      params = tensor_forest.ForestHParams(
      num_classes=_num_classes, num_features=_num_features,
      num_trees=_num_trees, max_nodes=_max_nodes, min_split_samples=3)

    graph_builder_class = tensor_forest.RandomForestGraphs
    return random_forest.TensorForestEstimator(
      params, graph_builder_class=graph_builder_class,
      model_dir=_model_dir)
```

This function stores the textual model to graph.pbtxt file in the specified model directory.

Then I train it using:

```
est = build_estimator(output_model_dir, 3,np.size(features_eval,1), 5,6)
train_X = features_eval.astype(dtype=np.float32)
train_Y = labels_y.astype(dtype=np.float32)
est.fit(x=train_X, y=train_Y, batch_size=np.size(features_eval,0))
```

(in this simple example: number of trees = 5, max_nodes=6)

Now I want to freeze the model, so I call this function:

```
def save_model_android(model_path):
checkpoint_state_name = "model.ckpt-1"
input_graph_name = "graph.pbtxt"
output_graph_name = "freezed_model.pb"
checkpoint_path = os.path.join(model_path, checkpoint_state_name)

input_graph_path = os.path.join(model_path, input_graph_name)
input_saver_def_path = None
input_binary = False
output_node_names = "output"
restore_op_name = "save/restore_all"
filename_tensor_name = "save/Const:0"
output_graph_path = os.path.join(model_path, output_graph_name)
clear_devices = True

freeze_graph(input_graph_path, input_saver_def_path,
                          input_binary, checkpoint_path,
                          output_node_names, restore_op_name,
                          filename_tensor_name, output_graph_path,
                          clear_devices, "")
```

and in the freezed_model.pb file generated I get only 1 op which is the output node.
in the console I get the following message when the freeze_graph function is called:

```
Converted 0 variables to const ops.
1 ops in the final graph.
```

Does anyone knows why only one node get exported when calling to freeze_graph?

I'm using Tensorflow version 1.2.1 with cuda support , installed from sources on linux

Answer (score 0):

i faced the same question, but the code fo convert can transfer another ckpt model to pb smoothly ,  there is wrong when transfer CKPT model of deeplabV3, i have no idea.

the transfer code is blow:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework import graph_util
from tensorflow.python.platform import gfile

def freeze_graph(ckpt, output_graph):
output_node_names = "logits/biases"
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(ckpt+'.meta', clear_devices=False)
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
input_graph_def = graph.as_graph_def()

with tf.Session() as sess:
saver.restore(sess, ckpt)
output_graph_def = graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(
sess=sess,
input_graph_def=input_graph_def,
output_node_names=output_node_names.split(',')
)
with tf.gfile.GFile(output_graph, 'wb') as fw:
fw.write(output_graph_def.SerializeToString())
print ('{} ops in the final graph.'.format(len(output_graph_def.node)))

ckpt = './6/model.ckpt'
pb = './6/modelxxxxxx.pb'

if __name__ == '__main__':
freeze_graph(ckpt, pb)
```

Answer (score 0):

the question solved, i need add another output  node in grapy
just like :
https://github.com/GeorgeSeif/Semantic-Segmentation-Suite/issues/63